# FlatList inside FlatList scrolling problem

Tags: react-native

I want to put a FlatList inside another one, but the child flatlist not scrolling.

I tried to convert the child FlatList to ScrollView, put the props scrollEnabled to false to the parent FlatList and both not work.

Here is a code example of what I want to do: https://snack.expo.io/HJ6d97gNH

I expect to scroll inside both flatlist, not only one.

Answer (score 2):

use **nestedScrollEnabled** in inner Flatlist for enabling the scrolling activity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`nestedScrollEnabled`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled) prop but I would recommend using a [`<SectionList>`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) since this is somehow buggy!